# Копирование строк из первой таблицы во вторую

Tags: access, delphi

Здравствуйте!

Прошу помощи, не могу разобраться в коде. Есть две таблицы (Таблица1 и Таблица2), так вот из второй таблицы на первую должны копироваться две строки (Imya и Fam), а у меня почему то копирует все, что есть во второй таблице. Программирую на Delphi БД Access. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('INSERT INTO Таблица1 (Imya, fam, Adres, Nom) ');
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('SELECT Imya, fam, Adres, Nom');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('FROM Таблица2');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM Таблица2';
```

Comment: Почитайте про sql, в этом коде особо ничего не понятно, но выборку вы делаете полную  `SELECT *`, и вставляете все поля (`Imya, fam, Adres, Nom`)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так? :)

```
ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('INSERT INTO Таблица1 (Imya, fam) ');
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('SELECT Imya, fam');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('FROM Таблица2');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM Таблица1';
```

ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM **Таблица1**';

Comment: Зивянки попутал, (адрес и номер не нужны) у меня так и стоит: 

`ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('INSERT INTO Таблица1 (Imya, fam) ');
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('SELECT Imya, fam');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('FROM Таблица2');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM Таблица1';`

Но почему копируется вся таблица, если в таблице три человека, то копирует их всех, а мне нужно, чтоб копировало только одного?!

Comment: Добавьте необходимое услове WHERE:


    ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE Imya="123"');

Я не знаю точного синтаксиса, но думаю, должно быть понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется вы не понимаете как реализовать запросы к БД.
Если нужно выборка,то есть нужно в результате что то получить, (поле,столбцы, и тд)
то нужно вместо `ExecSql;` просто открыть `Open;`
ExecSql логично применять когда обновляем,записываем,или удаляем с базы (update,insert,delete). 
А если скажем

```
AdoQuery.sql:='select * from table';
Adoquery.ExecSql;//запрос выполниться 1 раз,P.S: это 'лишняя'
Adoquery.open;//запрос выполниться 2 раз
```

В вашем случае, логика должно быть таким:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('INSERT INTO Таблица1 (Imya, fam) ');
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.add('SELECT Imya, fam');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('FROM Таблица2');
ADOQuery1.Open;
```